# AUTO SMS using C#.NET after entering the values into database?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a table with the following structure Client_Id,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5, Client_Order, Quantity.

Now my requirement is i need to send automatic Sms from database when the Order given by client for Pizza, Burger etc. Suppose any client order the pizza and type of pizza quantity of pizza then if we enter the values into the Fields then all the values will store into database and then we PRESS the SUBMIT or OK BUTTON and after click on the button and there should generate an auto SMS to user Or Client on that number from where he/she call USING C#.NET.

Comment: Hi AGHA, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Try to create the sql agent. Call that agent when user perform the submit event. In sql agent call the trigger in which u write the sms sending code.

Answer (score 0):

Create the sql agent. Call that agent when user perform the insert something into table. In sql agent call the trigger in which u write the sms sending code.So when the Trigger fire the sms sending perform automatically.

```
[Check below link][1]
```